# Jquery displaying autocomplete result on a different DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have the following jquery code

```
$('#search-name').autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('.staff-format ul').empty();
    },
    source: ["James", "Katy", "Jessica", "Catherine", "Paul", "Frank"]
}).data('search-name')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<li/>')
   .data('item.search-name', item)
   .append(item.value)
   .appendTo($('.staff-format ul'));
};
```

with the following HTML

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input class="field" id="search-name" name="search-name" type="text" />
    <input class="submit" id="search-button" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<div class="staff-format">
    <ul class="staff-list">
        <!-- CONTENT WILL BE DYNAMICALLY PUT HERE -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

i am using this jquery UI framework

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

However i am getting this kind of error:

***TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined***

The autocomplete works perfectly if i type the associated keyword. But the result is not being displayed where i want it to be.